# Mysql event using php script

Tags: php, mysql

Hi this is my code run a script concept is when user check in first time user data insert to a table called tbl1 and at the same time we add a mysql event so that after few times later data from tbl1 move from tbl2 and tbl1 row data will delete i am set a cookie for event so that it will run after check box sumit i get the event and i also get the cookie on client computer and at the first time when user click on checkbox data inserting is also ok but problem is no data remove from the data base i mean from tbl1 and nothing insert in tbl2 after 3 minutes as i set event to do my code is

This is my script when any registed user click on checkbox then he insert tbl1 table and we set a cookie and run events after 36 minute event will run and insert data in to another table called tbl2 my code is

```
 <form action="course01.php" method="POST">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chk1" value="701" />I am agree with the course terms and condition<br/>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="enrolment"/>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>

    <?php
    include("config.php");
    session_start();
    $user=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
    $checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];
    if ($_POST["submit"]=="enrolment")
    {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,name,url FROM tbl0 WHERE id = '".$checkbox1."'");
    if (!$result) {
        echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    echo $row[0]; 
    echo $row[1]; // the email value
    echo $row[2];

    setcookie('joytestcookie','".$user."',time()+3600);
    setcookie('joytestcookie2','".$row[1]."',time()+3600);
    $query= "INSERT INTO tbl1 (course_id,course_name,course_url,username,entry_date) values ('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."','".$row[2]."','".$user."',localtime())";

    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $insertquery="CREATE EVENT $_cookie['joytestcookie2']
        ON SCHEDULE  AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE
        DO
          BEGIN
           insert into tbl2 (username,course_name) select username,couse_name from course_entry where name='".$_COOKIE['joytestcookie']."';
            delete from tbl1 where name ='".$_COOKIE['joytestcookie']."';
                  END";

     mysql_query($insertquery) or die (mysql_error());
    echo "Record is inserted";
    header("Location: z.php");  

    }

    ?>
```

tbl0 is another table so no  need to worry about.

Comment: You have serious security issues, you're using $_COOKIE directly in a SQL query. Please use pdo.

Comment: I will use mysqli later on

Comment: Use session data the code working fine, it's work as i expected but there r a problem and that is the event name,how to change it randomly.. any suggestion

Comment: Use the `rand()` function.

Comment: gudgip can't use the rand() function can you plz in more detail

Comment: `$row[1]` that is your event name now, right? You could do `$eventname = $_cookie['joytestcookie2'] . rand();`

Comment: yahooooo finally my work is done .... now able to create event individual name. gudgip your  method is not working.

Comment: Then how did you get it to work? Because your question was to make the event name random.

Answer (score -1):

my answer

```
function rand_string( $length ) {
            $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";  

            $size = strlen( $chars );
            for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
                $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
            }

            return $str;
        }

    $random=rand_string(5);

    $query= "INSERT INTO course_entry (course_id,course_name,course_url,username,entry_date,event_no) values ('".$row[0]."','".$row[1]."','".$row[3]."','".$user."',localtime(),'".$random."' )";
    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT event_no  FROM course_entry WHERE course_id='".$row[0]."' and username ='".$user."'");
    $joy =  mysql_fetch_row($res)   ;


    $insertquery="CREATE EVENT $joy[0]
        ON SCHEDULE  AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
        DO
          BEGIN
           insert into course_finish (course_id, username, course_name) select username,course_name,course_id from course_entry where username = '".$user."';

    delete from course_entry where username = '".$user."';
          END";

     mysql_query($insertquery) or die (mysql_error());
    echo "Record is inserted";
    header("Location: member.php"); 

    }
```

Comment: Insecure code, obsolete mysql_ API, invalid info supplied to `Location` header.. you basically made mistake everywhere you could. -1 so people who stumble upon this don't accidentally copy this atrocity.